# Find matrix of linear map of polynomials

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-calculus

For the question below, I am not sure how to find the desired matrix relative to the standard basis.  $P_3$ refers to polynomials with up to degree $3$

Thanks in advance

> for the linear map
>
> $$T:P_3(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathbb{R^4}, p\mapsto \big(p(0), p(1), p\prime(0), p\prime(1)  \big)$$
>
> a) Find the matrix $[T]_\beta^\gamma$ of $T$ relative to the standard bases of $P_3(\mathbb{R})$ and of $\mathbb{R^4}$
>
> b) Show that $T$ is an isomorphism

Comment: Do you know the definition of a linear transformation's matrix with respect to certain basis? If so, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Let $B := \{1, X, X^2, X^3\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}_{\leq3}[X]$, and $B' = \{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$. Now, by definition, $[T]_{B}^{B'}$ has on column $i$ the coordinates in $B'$ of the image of the $i$-th vector of $B$. So, since $B'$ is the canonical basis, taking coordinates is redundant: it suffices to place $T(X^{i-1})$ in each column $i$. So,

$$
T(1) = (1,1,0,0)\\
T(X) = (0,1,1,1)\\
T(X^2) = (0,1,0,2)\\
T(X^3) = (0,1,0,3)
$$

and therefore,

$$[T]_{B}^{B'}= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$

To finish we must conclude that $T$ is an isomorphism. This follows from the fact that $[T]_{B}^{B'}$ is invertible, since

$$\det
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix} = 
\det \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1 & 1\\
    1 & 0 & 0\\
    1 & 2 & 3
\end{bmatrix} =
\det \begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 1\\
    2 & 3
\end{bmatrix} = 1 \neq 0
$$